# PHP unusual bug with debug_print_backtrace

Tags: php, debugging

On my site, users can create pages, and assign collaborators. In my `Page` object, I store the collaborators as `User` objects in an array.

I also have a method called `collaborators` which accepts numerous different parameter types in order to manipulate the collaborators. For instance, if `null` is passed, it returns the existing collaborators. If an array is passed, it adds each user in the array to the array of collaborators.

This is my collaborators method:

```
public function collaborators($user = null)
{
    if(is_null($this->collaborators) || $user === true){

        if($this->resource_id() === false){
            $this->collaborators = array();
        } else {
            $result = $this->db->query("
                /** This retrieves collaborator user IDs **/
            ", array(
                $this->resource_id()
            ));

            $this->collaborators = array();

            foreach($result->result() as $user){
                $this->collaborators[] = new User($user->global_user_id);
            }
        }
    }

    if(is_null($user)){
        return $this->collaborators;
    } else if(is_string($user)){
        if(User::is_valid_id($user)){
            $this->collaborators[] = new User($user);
        }
    } else if(is_array($user)){
        foreach($user as $u){
            if($u instanceof User){
                $this->collaborators[] = $u;
            } else if(User::is_valid_id($u)){
                $this->collaborators[] = new User($u);
            }
        }
    } else if($user instanceof User){
        $this->collaborators[] = $user;
    } else {

        var_dump($user);
        throw new InvalidParametersException();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

In my view, I use a foreach loop to loop through collaborators to output them:

```
foreach($page->collaborators() as $user){ /** do stuff **/ }
```

As you can see in the collaborator method, if the object collaborator property is null, it retrieves data from the database. All subsequent calls to `collaborators()` retrieves the array from the `collaborators` property.

I have 2 problems:

I'm getting the following backtrace in my view:

```
object(stdClass)#529 (1) { ["global_user_id"]=> string(36) "8c9752fe-40d0-4259-bfe7-a5dcea7cbdfa" } 

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidParametersException' with message 'There was an error while trying to process your request. Please try again later.' in application/libraries/objects/MinisiteResource.php:423 

Stack trace: 
#0 application/views/department_site/page.php(153): MinisiteResource->collaborators()
#1 system/core/Loader.php(833): include('/...') 
#2 system/core/Loader.php(419): CI_Loader->_ci_load(Array) 
#3 application/libraries/Pages.php(98): CI_Loader->view('department_site...', Array) 
#4 application/controllers/department/minisite.php(574): Pages->build_page('department_site...', Array) 
#5 [internal function]: Minisite->pages('8', '40') 
#6 system/core/CodeIgniter.php(359): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) 
#7 /v in application/libraries/objects/MinisiteResource.php on line 423
```

This backtrace does't make sense. You can see `#0` is calling MinisiteResource->collaborators(). This defaults to a null parameter, so should return an array from the `collaborators()` method. However, for some reason its actually being passed an `stdClass` object from somewhere.

Now I want to know where this `stdClass` object is coming from, and **this is my second problem**

I add an extra line of code, to catch `stdClass` objects:

```
} else if($user instanceof stdClass) { echo 'Testing'; debug_print_backtrace(); exit; }
```

However, when I run this code, my page goes blank. I know for a fact that this segment of code IS running, but `debug_print_backtrace()` is failing. If I remove the `debug_print_backtrace()` call, I get 'Testing' outputted.

Obviously, if I can find out where the `stdClass` is being injected into the method, I can work out all my problems. But the main problem is `debug_print_backtrace()` is outputting nothing, and I can't rely on the Exception trace because for some reason it's not reliable.

**Why would `debug_print_backtrace()` not display anything? There's definately enough method calls up to this point which should output at least something**

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
foreach($result->result() as $user){
   $this->collaborators[] = new User($user->global_user_id);
}
```

After `foreach` is done `$user` still hangs in memory, and it is a proper `stdClass`. Just rename it to something else and you're fine.

Comment: You are a genius! Can't believe I missed that. I will accept your answer and +1 when it allows me to (6 minutes)